# I'm not getting my fragment layout reference in Fragment class(top_section_fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my fragment layout top_section_fragment.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >`enter code here`
      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:width="250dp"
          android:height="50dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="100dp"></EditText>

      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="299dp"
          android:text="Click Here"></Button>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my fragment class TopSectionFragment.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

    import java.util.zip.Inflater;

    public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment)
            return view;

        }
    }
```

I'm not getting my fragment layout in fragment class using R.layout.top_section_fragment

Comment: And what are you getting?

Comment: cannot find symbol top_section_fragment

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches/Restart, under the File menu.

Comment: I think it might be caused by fact that `inflate()` doesn't take only one parameter, like `setContentView()` does.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to import your `R` class.  Separately, SkypeDogg's point about `inflate(...)` stands.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container, false);
return view;
```